# Indoor (London) Phoenix Robelini- Date-palm

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, palm

I have an issue with my indoor Palm. I've had it for about 6 years and it's always been super happy in the same position. My issue that new fronds have appeared but are not opening after a number of months. The only variable here is that I've repotted it in a bigger pot. I've attached some pictures. Hoping I might be able to get some suggestions from this fine group.
Thanks

Symon[plam[image: palm]

Comment: It's dark for a palm tree, needs more light?